# Create network file share from an API

Tags: nfs, samba, smb, documentum, network-share

I am exploring the possibilities of exposing an EMC Documentum folder, and the files/folders within, as a network file share.

The reason is so we can enable another application to read and write files to what it thinks is a standard UNC path, but really the repository is in Documentum.

That Documentum product doesn’t seem to offer this, however does expose an API.

A few thoughts here were a bespoke ‘driver’ for SAMBA, possibly something using WebDAV, but really I haven’t investigated these much yet, so both may be unviable.

Basically, how can I wrap an API up to look like a network drive?

I’ll keep self exploring this but hopefully someone can provide some leads here too..?

Update: using FUSE for Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We identified that we can use FUSE on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Documentum "folder" as you see it is not something like Windows folder. It is a database record of object with its related properties. Nothing else.

Documentum "documents" are somehow more related to Windows documents but still are only database record of objects with related properties and specific content stored somewhere in storage. Storage can be something like:

- file share on Windows / Linux OS
- specialized storage soluton like
  Centra
- specialized storage cloud solution

So you have misunderstanding of what you call Documentum folder. Your requirement can still be achieved in some way, thats for sure. 
For example you could make integration between windows folder to Documentum via Spring Intergration framework (SI) from Windows folder side and at Documentum side implement listeners to hook SI and implement BOF (Business Object Framework) services to process events from SI. This is just one of the options.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I’m aware of the way it’s represented within Documentum, but wanted to use language to help the understanding of the outcome. Can you suggest additional options? We cannot assume just Windows, in fact the client could be Linux or MacOS.

Comment: Windows/Linux/Unix/MacOS share same paradigm regarding folders and I'm pretty sure Spring Integration supports all of them.

Comment: btw, depending on product solution for the Documentum platform you will use you have OOTB solutions to integrate with 3rd party systems.

Comment: Do you know what OOTB features are available in Documentum?

Comment: Do you know which product solution on Documentum platform you will use?

Comment: The name of the product is D2

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible to create an interface to Documentum repository using any standard (SMB, CIFS, WebDav, IMAP, .... ) which can represent a document.

The fun task / hard part is mapping Documentum functionality to your chosen standard.

For example: back in 2013 I wrote a basic proof of concept Webdav interface to Documentum repository. I used the Miltion WebDav java library (http://milton.io).
With a WebDav interface, the Documentum Repository was exposed to a Windows computer as a drive using *Add Network Location*.